# Why is the Invoke of an assembly taking so much RAM?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, memory-leaks, memory-management

I'm successfuly running assembly (exe) from byte array. My code is:

```
public static void Execute(byte[] assembly, string arg) {
     if (assembly[0x3c] == 0x80) { 
          object[] o = new object[] { new string[] { arg } };
          try {
              Assembly.Load(assembly).EntryPoint.Invoke(null, o);
          } catch (TargetInvocationException e) {
              throw e.InnerException;
          }
     } else {
          throw new Exception("File is not a valid .NET assembly.");
     }
}
```

All fine, but the executable keeps leaking memory. The original needs 6-10MB, this one after the run produces 40-60 and up to 145mb (and then drops down to 10 and loops again).

Why is this happening, what leaks memory and any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not leaking memory; you're seeing the effects of garbage collection.  Garbage collection can be deferred until some point in the future, when the system determines that it needs more memory; that's what's happening in your instance when the process usage suddenly drops.

Don't worry about it; it's perfectly normal.  Moreover, it's the way the system is designed; this behavior is not affecting your execution time or overall memory usage.

Comment: Yes, but the gc memory buffer must be filled to be freed. So  I think it somehow fills it up and then collects it. It usually gets up to 10mb, now it's like 150mb.

Comment: 150mb is just too much, I have to make it lower somehow.

Comment: @blez, as soon as _any_ process on your machine requires memory when memory is low, .NET will perform garbage collection and clean up the junk it's left lying around.  Some people like to keep their house neat and tidy at all times, and some people like to clean only when guests are coming over.  .NET resembles the latter.  Regardless, the guests (other processes) only ever see a clean house.

Comment: So it saves processing resources

Comment: My app is _idle_ it doesn't do anything. So it shouldn't allocate that much memory. The inner executable while idle allocates up to 10mb.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances you don't have an N+1 copy of the assembly (the byte array) in memory. I would look there for your disparity.